# Как перехватить oledbexception

Tags: c#

Кидаю код полностью. И объясняю что у меня происходит. Пишу обыкновенный простенький менеджер паролей, в первую очередь для себя. Приложение подсоединяется к базе данных, в которой собственно все и хранится. В базе данных есть строки обязательные к заполнению, где я запретил ввод пустых строк. Как мне перехватить исключение oledbexception которое возникает при вводе пустых строк, и выдать пользователю окно с уведомлением что он ввел пустую строку? Я смотрел примеры try и cath в инете но не все понял.

Собственно сам код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace manager_password
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void t1BindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Validate();
        this.t1BindingSource.EndEdit();
        ///try
        ///{
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.bd001DataSet);
        //}
        //catch (OLEdbException)


    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: данная строка кода позволяет загрузить данные в таблицу "bd001DataSet.t1". При необходимости она может быть перемещена или удалена.
        this.t1TableAdapter.Fill(this.bd001DataSet.t1);

    }

    private void описаниеLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void описаниеTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

И, собственно, то место, где я пытался выловить вышеупомянутое исключение.

```
private void t1BindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Validate();
    this.t1BindingSource.EndEdit();
    ///try
    ///{
        this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.bd001DataSet);
    //}
    //catch (OLEdbException)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try
{
    this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.bd001DataSet);
}
catch (OleDbException e)
{
    // user message
    // or throw new OleDbException(e.Message, e);
}
```

Comment: Говорит что пропущена директива на сборку... может просто сделать перехват Exception, ну типа стандартный. От него ведь все остальные наследуются? Или я что то не понял...?

Comment: Да, верно. Можете в Debug-режиме перехватить обычный Exception и посмотреть какой тип исключения выкидывает ваш код

Comment: Так вот я уже сделал. Говорит - выкидывает oledb. Сейчас скину

Comment: вот ссылка на скрин  http://www.ex.ua/417821111186

Comment: не открывается, кстати по поводу директивы проверьте есть ли в using это using System.Data.OleDb;

Comment: спасибо, Ваш, комментарий помог, сделал перехват, все работает. Теперь следующий вопрос.. что за баг происходит при дебаге? Ошибок никаких нет ссылка та же что и вверху, файл icevideo

Comment: проверил, только что - работает, попробуйте еще раз. если не откроет - загружу на яндекс диск. using добавил

Comment: ex.ua заблокирован в РФ :)

Comment: можно конкретней? "что за баг происходит при дебаге?"

Comment: Вот ссылка на запись видео с экрана во время дебага. 

https://yadi.sk/i/ybT6w44hnsfLs     суть в чем. поле сервис (комбобокс) заменяет данные что ли.. я  хз как это описать. посмотрите, там видно